# Could not load type 'System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker' from assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this error:

> Could not load type 'System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker' from assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I have tried, but cannot solve this problem.

Comment: Hi Indra suandi! Can you edit your question and add the code that is throwing the exception?

Comment: no i dnt have it